# configure apache with tomcat and ssl

Tags: apache, tomcat6

How can I configure apache with ssl to redirect to a tomcat http?

I have a virtualHost on .80 redirecting to .443 and on the virtualHost .443 
I put the rewriteCond and the Proxypass is that the right configuration?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through mod_jk. See http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/quick.html.